# HTTP request DateTime Format

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I have been given assignment where i have to respond in my rest api with

```
date of creation formatted in requester s local date format
```

I am having trouble figuring out what to do.
I checked Http headers but couldn't find anything i could use.
Should i take "Date" header from HTTP request and check formatting?
Is there some kind of mechanism i can achieve it easily?

Tried doing following code but i always get defaultValue instead of Date

```
    @RequestHeader(value="Date", defaultValue="foo") String Date,
```

I am not able to ask for more information person that gave me the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

Extract the user's locale from the request as `locale = HttpServletRequest.getLocale()`.

**Step 2**

Create a date formatter for that locale as `formatter = java.text.DateFormat(DateFormat.LONG, locale)`.

**Step 3**

Finally, format the date of interest as `formatter.format(creationDate)`.